firebase_storage pod error in flutter ios
I am uploading image to firebase. It is working fine on android, but in iOS there is a run time error and app crashes.
here is the code causing error:
appCheck = ComponentType<AppCheckInterop>.instance(for: AppCheckInterop.self,
                                                   in: app.container)!

and the error is:

FirebaseStorage/Storage.swift:294: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

solution to upload image on firebase without app crash

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

i have found the solution
add: 'await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();'
in your main
works for me
